# Merge mixin in vue

Tags: json, vue.js, mixins

I'm working in vue/quasar application.
I've my mixin like this in my view.cshtml

```
var mixin1 = {
        data: function () {
            return { data1:0,data2:'' }
        }
        ,
        beforeCreate: async function () {
            ...}
        },
        methods: {
            addformulaire(url) {
               
            },
            Kilometrique() {  }
          
        }
    }
```

And I want merge with my content in js file (it's to centralize same action an severals cshtml)

```
const nomeMixins = {
data: function () {
    return { loadingcdt: false, lstclt: [], filterclient: [], loadingdoc: false, lstdoc: [], filterdoc: [] }
},
computed: {
    libmntpiece(v) { return "toto"; }
},
methods: {
    
    findinfcomplemtX3(cdecltx3, cdedocx3) {
        
    },
    preremplissagex3: async function (cdecltx3, cdedocx3) {
       
        }
    }
}
```

};

I want merge this 2 miwin in one. But when I try assign or var mixin = { ...mixin1,  ...nomeMixins };
I've only mixin1 nothing about methods,data from my js file nomeMixins but merging failed cause I've same key in my json object. I'm trying to make a foreach but failed too

Someone try to merge to mixin / json object with same key in the case you've no double child property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working and searching... I find [this one](https://dev.to/fdietz/vue-js-mixins-extending-components-and-high-order-components-2gfb) And understand that I can add directly mixin in my compoment (don't laught I'm begging with vue few months ago)

my custommiwin.js

```
const DataLoader = Vue.mixin({
data: function () {
    return { loadingcdt: false, lstclt: [], filterclient: [], loadingdoc: false, lstdoc: [], filterdoc: [] }
},
methods: {
    filterClt: async function (val, update, abort) {
        if (val.length < 3) { abort(); return; }
        else {//recherche
            this.loadingcdt = true;
            let res = await axios...
            this.loadingcdt = false;
        }
        update(() => {
            const needle = val.toLowerCase();
            this.filterclient = this.lstclt.filter(v => v.libelle.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1 || v.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1);
        })
    },
    filterDocument: async function (val, update, abort, cdecltx3) {
        if (!cdecltx3 || val.length < 3) { abort(); return; }
        else {//recherche
            this.loadingdoc = true;
            let res = await axios({ ...) }
            this.loadingdoc = false;
        }
        update(() => {
            const needle = val.toLowerCase();
            this.filterdoc = this.lstdoc.filter(v => v.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1);
        })
    },      
}
```

});

and in my compoment.js I add this

```
 mixins: [DataLoader],
```

I include all my js file in my cshtml file

Comment: the article is plain wrong; I wonder how your problem gets solved. Please refer my updated answer.

Comment: Plain wrong, I'm not qualify for say that, but it's just show me how add mixin in a compoment. I use it in 2 compoments, like I write and it's works very well. But thanks for advertise it's always to notice them.

Answer (score 1):

You cant merge mixins in that way. the spread syntax will overwrite keys e.g `data`, `computed`, `methods` etc and final result will not be suitable for your purpose.

refer [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) for adding mixins in your component. Also note that You can easily add multiple mixins in any component, so I don't think combination of two mixins will be any useful.

### UPDATE

reply to `YannickIngenierie` answer and pointing out mistakes in [this article](https://dev.to/fdietz/vue-js-mixins-extending-components-and-high-order-components-2gfb)

1. Global Mixins are not declared like this

```js
// not global mixin; on contrary MyMixin is local
// and only available in one component.

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  mixins: [MyMixin]
});
```

2. Local Mixins are not declared like this

```js
// NOT local mixin; on contrary its global Mixin
// and available to all components

const DataLoader = Vue.mixin({....}}

Vue.component("article-card", {
  mixins: [DataLoader], // no need of this
  template: "#article-card-template",
  created() {
    this.load("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
  }
});
```

Point is refer documentation first before reading any article written by some random guy, including me. Do slight comparison what he is saying whats in documentation.